# Gaining residency in Italy when working for non-Italian employers

Tags: residency, working, uk-citizens, italy, brexit

I am a UK citizen currently working for both a UK university and a Dutch organisation and I pay UK income tax through PAYE. My partner (also a UK citizen) is currently between jobs but plans to set up a remote teaching business. We would like to permanently relocate to Italy.

What would be the obstacles to us gaining permanent residency in Italy prior to the end of the Brexit implementation period on 31st Dec 2020?

I don't want to over-complicate this question but we're specifically confused whether one or both of us would need to be employed *in Italy* to gain resident status?

Comment: To gain residency in Italy, you must fulfill the conditions of [Article 7 (1)(a, b) Directive 2004/38/EC](https://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/EN/TXT/?uri=CELEX:02004L0038-20110616). Your work for the Dutch organisation may be sufficient for the condition (**b**) : *have sufficient resources for themselves and their family members not to become a burden...*

Comment: @MarkJohnson thanks! We have been going over this text and wondering what "sufficient resources" might mean, specifically, in this context and whether it's written down anywhere in black and white... lots of fun.

Comment: If you have been living from these resources in the past, then why shouldn't it be sufficient for the future?